# Сделать многошаговую форму в Django?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django

Мне нужно сделать форму в несколько шагов (3-4 шага), без использования form-tools, подскажите как такое реализовать? Нужны ли сессии для этого?

**forms.py:**

```
class Form1(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200, label="Имя")
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200, label="Фамилия")


class Form2(forms.Form):
    field_3 = forms.CharField(max_length=200, label="Поле 3")
    field_4 = forms.CharField(max_length=200, label="Поле 4")
```

Comment: Сохранение между шагами важно? Нужна валидация каждого шага? Если да -> делайте отдельные вьюхи, если нет -> храните все на клиенте(записывайте JS'ом в переменные), а потом отправляйте на одну форму в джангу.

Comment: Валидация каждого шага нужна, возврат на прошлый шаг с  ранее введённым данными не принципиальна, но было бы большим плюсом.

Comment: Почему без использования form-tools?

Comment: Есть такое ограничение и всё.

Comment: Не подскажете как быть если на одном из шагов FileField ?